# Left join using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm building a WPF app using Visual Studio 2015 against Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server 2008. I have these two tables:

```
Employee
-----------------------------
EmployeeId
FirstName
LastName
... other columns

EmployeeStatus
-----------------------------
EmployeeStatusId
EmployeeId (Foreign Key to Employee.EmployeeId)
ValidEmployeeStatusId
```

The app needs to fetch all employees whose `EmployeeStatus.ValidEmployeeStatusId` is not 2 and not 4 (Inactive and Leave of Absence). I've written this LINQ query, but it just runs forever and never returns any results:

```
var query = (from e in context.Employees
             from es in context.EmployeeStatus
                .Where(x => e.employeeID == x.employeeID 
                    && (x.validEmployeeStatusID != 2
                    && x.validEmployeeStatusID != 4)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new EmployeeViewModel
             {
                 EmployeeId = e.employeeID,
                 /* set other properties*/
             });
return await Task.Run(() => new 
    ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(query));
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Found out what was killing me on the slowness... Each `EmployeeViewModel` was calling the database in its ctor to populate some ObservableCollections. Turned those properties into `static` and added a `static bool`; if it's false, populate the properties and set bool to true. So all instances use the same data for those properties that were calling the database. For ~4000 records, that was a lot of calls.

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. Left join after applying the criteria will include employees *having** `ValidEmployeeStatusId` 2 or 4. So, what should the query return if (A) there are no related `EmployeeStatus` records (B) there is related `EmployeeStatus` record with ``ValidEmployeeStatusId == 2` (C) there is related `EmployeeStatus` record with ``ValidEmployeeStatusId == 4`  (D) otherwise ?

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev. If an employee has a status, we want to exclude employees with status 2 and 4. But get all other employees.

Comment: So it's only one status record per employee record?

Comment: No, an employee can be both 2 and 4. Don't ask me, those were the requirements :)

Comment: See Update above on why query was so slow with the answer provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve desired result with a left join.

```
var query = (from e in context.Employees
             join es in context.EmployeeStatus
               on e.employeeID equals es.employeeID into empStatuses
             from emps in empStatuses.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where emps.validEmployeeStatusID != 2
                && emps.validEmployeeStatusID != 4
             select new EmployeeViewModel
             {
                 EmployeeId = e.employeeID,
                 /* set other properties*/
             });
```

Comment: Thanks, @dotctor. I updated the column names in my question above. Let me try your solution and see...

Comment: I'm only getting one result back because only one employee has a status set. Most employees won't have a status; I wish to fetch them too. How do I do that?

Comment: For that to be a left join you need `from emps in empStatuses.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Do I need to do `DefaultIfEmpty()` to perform a left join? It's still only returning one result.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to put `DefaultIfEmpty()`. fixed. @Alex

Comment: It seems to be working but it's taking forever. It should be returning about 4,000 `EmployeeViewModel` objects in the ObservableCollection. I've cancelled out of it

Comment: No matter how hard I try, the `into` statement does not make semantic sense to me to read. Why does there have to be three variable names when doing a left join? So confusing...

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to perform a `join`

Try this query

```
var query = (from e in context.Employees
             where e.EmployeeStatus.validEmployeeStatusID != 2 
           && e.EmployeeStatus.validEmployeeStatusID != 4
         select new EmployeeViewModel
         {
             EmployeeId = e.employeeID,
             /* set other properties*/
         });
```

Comment: It won't let me select `.validEmployeeStatusID` on `e.EmployeeStatus`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `!Any` based LINQ query which should be translated to SQL `NOT EXISTS` query, which IMO is a good alternative of a join nowadays. Also it avoids employee record duplication which happens when using joins.

```
var query = (from e in context.Employees
             where !context.EmployeeStatus.Any(s => e.employeeID == s.employeeID 
                 && (s.validEmployeeStatusID == 2 || s.validEmployeeStatusID == 4))
             select new EmployeeViewModel
             {
                 EmployeeId = e.employeeID,
                 /* set other properties*/
             });
```

You can also try the following join (actually [antijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29)) version of the query:

```
var query = (from e in context.Employees
             join s in context.EmployeeStatus
                 .Where(x => x.validEmployeeStatusID == 2 || x.validEmployeeStatusID == 4))
             on e.employeeID equals s.employeeID into statusGroup
             from s in statusGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where s == null
             select new EmployeeViewModel
             {
                 EmployeeId = e.employeeID,
                 /* set other properties*/
             });
```